# How can i use an ARIMA model to explain the an effect of news regarding COVID-19 on a stock market index?

Tags: forecasting, arima, finance, intervention-analysis, covid-19

My thoughts were to model the time series of the stock index up until the particular day for the news I am looking at and forecast using my model. Then I would compare the forecasted result to the actual observation, for example the effects 7 days after the news. Is this a proper approcah? And how far back do I need to go when i am looking at the daily returns? My problems so far are that when using R program and `auto.arima` funtion, I get an ARIMA(0,0,0) output. Also, the ACF and PACF of the time series give me the same results for order of p and q.

Comment: Why not go ahead and use ARIMA(0,0,0)? If this is the best model for your data (which it likely is among ARIMA models -- we know that from financial theory), why do you find it problematic?

Comment: This sound more like something you would do with segmented regression than ARIMA. Hays et el did a sage monograph in the early eighties using ARIMA which addresses intervention. Financial markets in theory should be white noise, so your findings are not surprising. If someone could run an ARIMA model and find useful things to predict financial markets they would have already. So it would be incorporated into reality. Or that is what the theory says.